# Double integral evaluation (polar coordinates solution verification)

Tags: polar-coordinates, multiple-integral

I have gotten this here integral to solve:
$$\iint xy\,\mathrm dx\mathrm dy$$where the area is bounded by $x^2+y^2=1$, $x^2+y^2=2x$, $y=0$.

So, from the conditions we have:
$$r^2=1,\ r=2\cos\theta,\ r\sin\theta =0.$$
If I draw a picture, I see that the area can be divided into two parts (above and below the x-axis), so I'd say it is sufficient to calculate the area of the part above the x-axis and multiply it by two to get the correct result.

Now, we're considering only the part above the x axis

From the last equation we can deduce that the angle goes from $ [0, \dfrac{\pi}{2}]$, since sine is zero at $\dfrac{\pi}{2}$.

Regarding the boundaries of $r$, I'm not sure how to determine them, because $r$ naturally is $[0,1]$. What I tried is $r \in [0,2\cos\theta]$

Now my integral is:

$$\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\int_0^{2\cos\theta} r^3cos\theta \sin\theta \,\mathrm dr\mathrm d\theta$$ which evaluates to $\dfrac{2}{3}$. After multiplying by $2$, I get $\dfrac{4}{3}$.

Is my solution correct?

Comment: Those bounds don't appear to make sense.  The two circles overlap in an ovalish shape,  the $y=0$ bisects it,  so the three curves don't have a simple region it bounds,  it makes 2 regions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple regions bound by $x^2+y^2 = 1$, $x^2+y^2 = 2x$ and $y = 0$. So the question should always state it clearly using inequality signs.

[image]

For example, if we are trying to integrate over the region shaded in the diagram, it should state

$x^2+y^2 \geq 1, x^2 + y^2 \leq 2x, y \geq 0$

Also note that at the intersection of both circles,

$x^2+y^2 = 2x = 1 \implies x = \cos\theta = \dfrac{1}{2}$. So $\theta = \dfrac{\pi}{3}$.

Therefore the integral for the region I have outlined in the diagram is,

$\displaystyle \int_0^{\pi/3} \int_1^{2\cos\theta} r^3 \sin\theta \cos\theta \ dr \ d\theta$

Comment: I knew the formulation of the exercise was ambiguous because it wasn't precise, so I assumed it's the area you marked as (3) on your picture. Just for curiosity's sake though, _could_ I express the boundaries for the angle for the area (3) so easily? By the way, thanks for the answer!

Comment: OK for region $3$, please write the inequalities as $x^2+y^2 \leq 1, x^2 + y^2 \leq 2x, y \geq 0$. For region $3$, when $\theta \in [0, \frac{\pi}{3}], r \in [0, 1]$ and when $\theta \in \left[\frac{\pi}{3}, \frac{\pi}{2}\right], r \in [0, 2 \cos\theta]$. Is it clear why?

Comment: hmm that is very interesting. I'm not sure why, because the intersection points of the two circles are the same as in (5). Could you explain a bit further?

Comment: Take a radial line from the origin, do you see that it is bound by circle $x^2+y^2 = 1$ for $\theta \in \left[0, \frac{\pi}{3}\right]$?

Comment: Whereas if you take a line from the origin with $\theta \geq \frac{\pi}{3}$, it is bound by the other circle. In region $5$, there is no area bound for $\theta \geq \frac{\pi}{3}$ and for $\theta \in \left[0, \frac{\pi}{3}\right]$, if you take a line from the origin, you see it intersects both circles and we are interested in $r \geq 1$ and $r \leq 2\cos\theta$.

Comment: thank you very much! I understand perfectly